# in windows phone,how to implement a android-like tabview like this?

Tags: windows-phone

[image: this picture is android's tabview][image: this is android-like tabview which in the pivot control]

**the first picture** is android's tabview
**the second picture** is android-like tabview which in the pivot control
tabview is in the *pivot page*’s **grid**
i'd like to have a result just like the second picture
any suggestions will be great!!!!!
thanks

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="ewlan.PivotMainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">



    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

//what's in here?
//i know pivot
//what i need to know is what in the pivot.item
//hope u can know my meanings,any suggestions will be great

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you create a new application and add a Pivot page, it will generate some pages in Pivot control. I suggest that you take a look at it and add the necessary controls. Take a look at the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941098%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more information. You will get something like this:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed.-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Pivot contains PivotItems which in turn contains your UI elements.